# static let calendar with autoupdatingCurrent time zone is not working

Tags: ios, swift, static, calendar, timezone

In my application I have a static `gregorian` property in `SharedCalendar` class that is defined like this:

```
static let gregorian: Calendar = {
    var calendar = Foundation.Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    calendar.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent
    return calendar
}()
```

When I want to access a day of some date in specific time zone I am calling:

```
SharedCalendar.gregorian.dateComponents([ .day ], from: someDate).day!
```

Let's say `someDate` is `Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 512658000.0)` which is `2017-03-31 13:00:00 +0000`.

When I start the app in Vancouver time zone the `SharedCalendar.gregorian.timeZone` property has value `America/Vancouver (autoupdatingCurrent)` and the result of `SharedCalendar.gregorian.dateComponents([ .day ], from: someDate).day!` is `31` **which is correct**.

When I put the application to background and switch the time zone to Sydney and run the app again the `SharedCalendar.gregorian.timeZone` property has value `Australia/Sydney (autoupdatingCurrent)` (which is correct), but the result of `SharedCalendar.gregorian.dateComponents([ .day ], from: someDate).day!` is `31` **which is wrong (should be `1`)**.

When I change the definition of `gregorian` property to be a `var`:

```
var gregorian: Calendar {
    var calendar = Foundation.Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    calendar.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent
    return calendar
}
```

Everything works properly, which is for `America/Vancouver (autoupdatingCurrent)` I get `31`, and for `Australia/Sydney (autoupdatingCurrent)` I get `1`.

Right now I don't quite understand how `TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent` is working. When device's time zone changes the `SharedCalendar.gregorian.timeZone` reflects the device's time zone, but it looks like `SharedCalendar.gregorian` is somehow using the old time zone.

Does anyone have explanation of this behaviour?

Comment: Not related to your question/issue but if you just need one component you can use calendar method `SharedCalendar.gregorian.component(.day, from: someDate)`

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus!

Answer (score 7):

I reported [radar](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5059074106327040) regarding this issue and today Apple responded:

> The reason that your `static let` calendar’s time zone doesn’t update is that you need to issue a call to `NSTimeZone.resetSystemTimeZone()` to sync up with the system time zone. See the documentation for `NSTimeZone.resetSystemTimeZone()` for more info: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimezone/1387189-resetsystemtimezone?language=objc
>
> The reason your `var` calendar works is because every call to the calendar property actually creates a new computed calendar, which happens to be set to a new time zone representing the current system time zone.

This makes sense, because `static let` caches system's time zone, and from documentation for `NSTimeZone.resetSystemTimeZone` we can read:

> If the application has cached the system time zone, this method clears that cached object. If you subsequently invoke systemTimeZone, NSTimeZone will attempt to redetermine the system time zone and a new object will be created and cached (see systemTimeZone).